# Godot - Ingore Windows (OS) scalling

Tags: windows, operating-system, scaling, highdpi, godot

When you search in Windows for "Display Settings" you will come to these settings:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/cxvQl]

Lets say you have a FullHD high DPI Screen, your scalling percentrage will be set to 125% (laptop comes with this setting per default, if you disable it, your icons will be too small to read).

If you then start a Godot game, this scalling/zoom will be applied to the game too. Which results in a zommed in version of the game and therefore a unplayable version of the game if you have this scalling turned on.

I have tried two solutions (marked in red), but they both don't help:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/aBXFc]

Any idea on how to solve this? Or is the scalling not the problem, but something else like the high DPI?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Noone that can help? :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to activate `allow_hidpi` setting on Project Settings, under "Display" category.